# Typescript generic base class with mapped type. How to initialize mapped type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to pass a type to my base class "AbstractGqlForm<T extends  {[Property  in  keyof T]: BehaviorSubject }>" to make my form system type safe.

Stackblitz minimum example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nbkd23?file=AddShiftForm.ts

AddShiftForm.ts

```
type AddShiftFormInputDef = {
 "start":  BehaviorSubject<{value: Date   , valid: boolean}>,
 "end":  BehaviorSubject<{value: Date  , valid: boolean}>,
 "name":  BehaviorSubject<{value: string, valid: boolean}>
}

export class AddShiftForm extends  AbstractGqlForm<AddShiftFormInputDef>{
 constructor(requiredInputs:RequiredInputs) {
 super(requiredInputs)
}
```

BaseGqlForm.ts:

```
export abstract class AbstractGqlForm<T extends  {[Property  in  keyof T]: 
BehaviorSubject<GqlFormInputStatus> }>{

protected inputSubjects: {[Property  in  keyof T]: BehaviorSubject<any>} | undefined;
protected constructor(requiredInputs:RequiredInputs) {
  this.requiredInputs = requiredInputs;
}

registerInput(inputName: keyof T, input$: BehaviorSubject<GqlFormInputStatus>) {
  if( this.inputSubjects === undefined){
    this.inputSubjects = {inputName: input$};
  }else{
    this.inputSubjects[inputName] = input$;
  }
}
```

GqlFormInputStatus.ts:

```
import {BaseGqlInput} from "./BaseGqlInputTypes";

export interface GqlFormInputStatus {
    value: BaseGqlInput | undefined ,
    valid: boolean
}


export interface TypedGqlFormInputStatus<T extends BaseGqlInput> {
    value: T  | undefined,
    valid: boolean
}
```

BaseGqlInputTypes.ts

```
export type BaseGqlInput = string | number | Date;
```

I have two problems.

1. I get an error in AddShiftForm when extending AbstractGqlForm:

> TS2344: Type 'AddShiftFormInputDef' does not satisfy the constraint '{ start: BehaviorSubject; end: BehaviorSubject; name: BehaviorSubject; }'.   The types of '"start".observers' are incompatible between these types.     Type 'Observer<{ value: Date; valid: boolean; }>[]' is not assignable to type 'Observer[]'.       Type 'Observer<{ value: Date; valid: boolean; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observer'

2. I cannot initialize inputSubjects like this:

   ```
    protected inputSubjects: {[Property  in  keyof T]: BehaviorSubject<any>} = {};
   ```

because I get the following error:

> TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ [Property in keyof T]: BehaviorSubject ; }'.

Thats why I try to initialize in registerInput but there I get following error in
`this.inputSubjects = {inputName: input$};`

> TS2322: Type '{ inputName: BehaviorSubject; }' is not assignable to type '{ [Property in keyof T]: BehaviorSubject; }'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'inputName' does not exist in type '{ [Property in keyof T]: BehaviorSubject; }'.

I am quite lost at the moment where to go on, and I am really really thankful for any help.

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible example. You did not share `BaseGqlInputTypes`. Please put it all in one place

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine BaseGqlInputTypes is in my question: export type BaseGqlInput = string | number | Date;
I will try to add an example. Thanks!

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine I just added a stackblitz example